# When I used tf.nn.read_file() to test an image in vgg, it was wrong.But when I used PIL to open it, it was correct. So strange

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I have written a vgg model, and trained it.Now, i'm going to test a new image.When I use code1, it works well, but it is wrong in code2.
vgg() is the model i defined it. And the ckpt file has been saved in "D:\Demo\ckpt".

code1: It printed prediction as [[  1.77901700e-01   8.22093844e-01   4.42284863e-06]]

```
def evaluate_one_image(path):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        image_plt = Image.open(path)
        image = image_plt.resize([224, 224])
        image_array = np.array(image)
        image = np.reshape(image_array, (1,224,224,3))
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 224, 224, 3])
        logit = vgg(x)
        logit = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
        logs_train_dir = 'D:\\Demo\\ckpt'
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(logs_train_dir)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)               
            prediction = sess.run(logit, feed_dict={x: image})
            print(prediction)
```

------------------------------------------------Dividing  Line--------------------------------------

code2: I used some functions in tensorflow.It printed prediction as [[ 0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33333334]].

```
def test_one_image(path):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        image_plt = Image.open(path)
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path), channels=3)
        image_tensor = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image_tensor, 224, 224)
        # image_tensor = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image_tensor)
        image_tensor = tf.reshape(image_tensor, [1, 224, 224, 3])
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 224, 224, 3])
        logit = vgg(x)
        logit = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
        logs_train_dir = 'D:\\Demo\\ckpt'
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(logs_train_dir)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)              
            prediction = sess.run(logit, feed_dict={x: image_tensor.eval()})
            print(prediction)
```

I think the two codes have nearly same steps.But I don't know why it's wrong, and how to handle it.Help me,thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First code **resize** image. Second code **crop** image. These are two different action, first action scales full image to new size, second action cuts of part of image to make it's size equal `224 x 224`

**Update:**

Try this code:

```
def test_one_image(path):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        image_plt = Image.open(path)
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path), channels=3)
        image_tensor = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor, [0])
        image_tensor = tf.image.resize_images(image_tensor, [224, 224])
        logit = vgg(image_tensor)
        logit = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
        logs_train_dir = 'D:\\Demo\\ckpt'
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(logs_train_dir)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)              
            prediction = sess.run(logit)
            print(prediction)
```

Comment: A new problem occured when i used "tf.image.per_image_standardization(image_tensor)". Do you have any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried,and it worked well.When I train the vgg model, I used tf.image.per_image_standardization() .When I test,should I use this function again?

Comment: I think so. But i think you will need resort commands in order: `decode_jpeg; resize_images; per_image_standardization; expand_dims;`

Answer (score 0):

When I used this code, error occured. The result was  [[ 0.33333334 0.33333334 0.33333334]] again.

```
def test_one_image(path):
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        image_plt = Image.open(path)
        image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.read_file(path), channels=3)
        image_tensor = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image_tensor)
        image_tensor = tf.reshape(image_tensor, [1, 224, 224, 3])
        x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 224, 224, 3])
        logit = vgg(x)
        logit = tf.nn.softmax(logit)
        logs_train_dir = 'D:\\Demo\\ckpt'
        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(logs_train_dir)
            saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)              
            prediction = sess.run(logit, feed_dict={x: image_tensor.eval()})
            print(prediction)
```